# UINavigation bar with custom image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want Custom navigation bar with size =60 .And In this navigation bar i add my custom image to this.
I write this code..

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

help me thanks in advance

Comment: Allright, so what's your question? What did you expect to see in your app? Please provide some more information.

Comment: @milan patel my answer solve your problem or not

Comment: No, this answer does not solve my problem...But I solve the problem with Add the image view to navigationBar ...

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

ok , you want to customize the height of navigation bar(according apple designing guildelines you  should ignored it but there are many beautiful apps in app store with customize navigation bar height).

the one way i got to  know to customize the navigation bar by  subclassing UINavigationBar and  and overvide the following method

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size 
{  
    CGSize customizeSize = CGSizeMake(customizeWidth , customizeWidthHeight);
    return customizeSize;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

`UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:SOMEFRAME];`
`imgView.image = SOMEIMAGE;`

`self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView;`

navigation bar has the property title view. U can add any Elements u want on it.

Comment: don't think it's a good practise to use navigationItem.titleView as the background of the navigation bar